# How to handle Number Format Exception null in java

Tags: java

> I just write a programme to find the leader of the game. Rule : After
> complete all the round of the game find the leader .Every round give
> points to both team and find the lead difference. At last find the
> huge lead difference which team get that team will be the winner.
> Below type of I write the program but I got Number format exception
> when receive the input from the user.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Codechef.main(Main.java:19)
```

> Alex.Java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Alex
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int cumScore1 = 0;
        int cumScore2 = 0;
        int maxLead = -1;
        int winner = -1;
        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int S = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            cumScore1 += S;
            cumScore2 += T;

            int lead = cumScore1 - cumScore2;
            if (Math.abs(lead) > maxLead) {
                maxLead = Math.abs(lead);
                winner = (lead > 0) ? 1 : 2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(winner + " " + maxLead);
    }
}
```

> I got error at this point.

```
int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

> Here Input and out put example

```
Input:

5
140 82
89 134
90 110
112 106
88 90
Output:

1 58
```

Comment: what inputs are causing this?

Comment: Now you can chek

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are accepting both player in a single line. Then you try to parse this line TO AN INT. Here parseInt will throw an exception because you cannot have a non-digit character in an int (here we have a space).

So you can split the line in two, then parse each part individually.

```
        String in[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
        if(in.length!=2) continue; // to avoid single number or empty line
        int S = Integer.parseInt(in[0]);
        int T = Integer.parseInt(in[1]);
```

But it will not save you from non digit characters. A [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class could be more useful, as it has methods like [hasNextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) and [nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()). So you will be much safer when reading input.

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int i = sc.nextInt();
```

- [Scanner example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-nextint-method-in-java-with-examples/)

Second solution would be to take each player from next line, so:

```
System.out.println("Player 1");
int S = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
System.out.println("Player 2");
int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

I got what causing the error. Logic wise the program is correct. The error is you input format.

> While you try to give input **140 82** like this in a single line the compiler assumes it as a string and reads as a string. So you are facing an error at parseInt.

Solution for this is:

> Either give input line by line or read it as a string and convert into array

Ex:

```
String ip = br.readLine();
String arr[] = ip.split(" ");
int S = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
int T = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
```